# Is it possible to run Docker CE in an azure VM?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine

If so, what vm image can I use?
This is purely for development purposes, and to simply run dev workloads on an azure VM that I can spin up and down as needed.

Docker CE for Windows says "Docker for Windows requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 10586, or Windows server 2016 RTM to run"

I just need a reasonable substitute than running locally since I am running windows 10 HOME on my laptop and would like to run Docker CE somewhere that actually works 100% of the time.

I tried the [Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with Containers] image that @win mentioned below, but it has enterrpise edition already installed out of the box, not CE

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with Containers.

[image]

Comment: this image is running Docker version 17.06.2-ee-10, build 66261a0 out of the box. Enterprise Edition, Im looking to run community edition, CE.

Comment: Also , according to Rolf Neugebauer of Docker, "Docker for Windows is only supported on Windows 10 and not Windows Server" https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1986

Comment: Container Host for Windows Server 2016 is different from Windows 10. However, CE vs EE should not affect on the containers you are running. –